# The trigger makes data unable to insert

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

hy, my trigger make me can't insert data to the table..

***this my trigger :***

```
CREATE 
    DEFINER = 'manager'@'%'
TRIGGER HRS_1.triggerCS
    AFTER INSERT
    ON HRS_1.transaksiChangeShift
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  
UPDATE transaksiChangeShift cs, (SELECT cs.idx, cs.NIK, cs.dateStart, cs.dateEnd FROM transaksiChangeShift cs ORDER BY cs.dateCreate DESC LIMIT 1)cs1
  SET cs.dateEnd = IF(cs.dateStart!=cs1.dateStart,IF(cs.dateStart=ADDDATE(cs1.dateStart, INTERVAL -1 DAY),NULL,ADDDATE(cs1.dateStart, INTERVAL -1 DAY)),NULL)
  WHERE cs.NIK=cs1.NIK AND (cs.dateEnd BETWEEN cs1.dateStart AND cs1.dateEnd or
  cs1.dateStart BETWEEN cs.dateStart AND cs.dateEnd) AND cs.idx<cs1.idx;

UPDATE transaksiChangeShift cs, (SELECT cs.idx, cs.NIK, cs.dateStart, cs.dateEnd FROM transaksiChangeShift cs ORDER BY cs.dateCreate DESC LIMIT 1)cs1
  SET cs.dateStart = IF(cs.dateStart!=cs1.dateStart,IF(cs.dateStart=ADDDATE(cs1.dateEnd, INTERVAL 1 DAY),NULL,ADDDATE(cs1.dateEnd, INTERVAL 1 DAY)),NULL)
  WHERE cs.NIK=cs1.NIK AND (cs.dateStart BETWEEN cs1.dateStart AND cs1.dateEnd AND cs.dateEnd > cs1.dateEnd) AND cs1.dateEnd IS NOT NULL AND cs.idx<cs1.idx;

DELETE
  FROM transaksiChangeShift 
  WHERE idx = (SELECT xx.idx from(SELECT
cs.idx
FROM transaksiChangeShift cs, (SELECT cs.idx, cs.NIK, cs.dateStart FROM transaksiChangeShift cs ORDER BY cs.dateCreate DESC LIMIT 1)cs1
  WHERE 
cs.NIK=cs1.NIK AND cs.dateStart=cs1.dateStart AND cs.dateEnd IS NULL AND cs1.idx>cs.idx)xx);

DELETE
  FROM transaksiChangeShift 
  WHERE idx = (SELECT xx.idx from(SELECT
cs.idx
FROM transaksiChangeShift cs, (SELECT cs.idx, cs.NIK, cs.dateStart, cs.dateEnd FROM transaksiChangeShift cs ORDER BY cs.dateCreate DESC LIMIT 1)cs1
  WHERE 
cs.NIK=cs1.NIK AND (cs.dateStart BETWEEN cs1.dateStart AND cs1.dateEnd AND cs.dateEnd IS NULL) AND cs1.idx>cs.idx)xx);


DELETE
  FROM transaksiChangeShift 
  WHERE idx = (SELECT xx.idx from(SELECT
cs.idx
FROM transaksiChangeShift cs, (SELECT cs.idx, cs.NIK, cs.dateStart, cs.dateEnd FROM transaksiChangeShift cs ORDER BY cs.dateCreate DESC LIMIT 1)cs1
  WHERE 
cs.NIK=cs1.NIK AND (cs.dateStart BETWEEN cs1.dateStart AND cs1.dateEnd AND cs.dateEnd <= cs1.dateEnd AND cs.dateStart >= cs1.dateStart) AND cs1.idx>cs.idx)xx);

END
```

when I insert, ***a pop up error will appear***:

> Can't update table 'transaksiChangeShift' in stored function/trigger
> because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
> function/trigger.

please help me to solve that,
thanks

Comment: That cannot be solved. The error message means that the table specified with the `AFTER INSERT` action cannot be used (for reading or writing) within the trigger's handling. Some other handling will be needed.

Comment: Trigger cannot solve, move your logic into stored procedure and call it instead of INSERT query.